# What is the related library in keras_benchmarks of tensorflow for data_generator?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run keras_benchmarks of tensorflow,
as I met the similar problem as https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/issues/91 did.

When I ran "python run_benchmark.py" in benchmarks/scripts/keras_benchmarks,

python told me:

> ImportError: No module named data_generator

I've installed and run things related to tf_cnn_benchmarks and can successfully do training real data on tf_cnn_benchmarks' all models,
but I still don't know where is data_generator.

Here's my Environment:

Ubuntu 16.04

CUDA 9.0/CuDNN 7.0

python 2.7

PS. I've searched the web and found that tensorflow have a library named "tensor2tensor", but it doesn't help when I do pip install and import it:
python still can't find generate_img_input_data in tensor2tensor's data_generators.(And it is named "data_generators", NOT "data_generator")

> from data_generators import generate_img_input_data
>
> ImportError: cannot import name generate_img_input_data

Am I right about the direction?
Or there are libraries else I should install and import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data_generator.py file is here  https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/keras_benchmarks/data_generator.py (it was added the same day you asked this question, so I guess it is not a coincidence?)

Comment: Actually, it's the owner's mistake that they haven't upload code completely.
The master branch they maintain was NOT uploaded with Keras code at that time.
However, the Keras part was deprecated.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought :)